# Sklearn Models unable to accept TFIDF vector inputs

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tf-idf

I have a random forest regression model. The idea is to predict salaries as a function of TFIDF vector inputs. The tokenization process works without hiccup. I'm unsure why the following error is being triggered:

```py
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
rfr = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=25)
rfr.fit(m0.tfidf,m0.target)

>>>> ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'UKN'
```

Where my input looks like this

```py
print(m0.tfidf)
>>>>

  (0, 81730)    0.08678124719228941
  (0, 81720)    0.4051829832483614
  (0, 81308)    0.02466923385401487
  (0, 80658)    0.09283202518518077
  (0, 79980)    0.037640159320294915
  (0, 78655)    0.08005811714948727
  (0, 78110)    0.1397255873105042
  (0, 78008)    0.03997373149323637
  (0, 77736)    0.04180617133028598
  (0, 77311)    0.05507981089212824
  (0, 76997)    0.10662513817286097
  (0, 75593)    0.027872186016968326
  (0, 75568)    0.043971243890655834
  (0, 74902)    0.04832667968768722
  (0, 73157)    0.022533926065197177
  (0, 72647)    0.0349761677792586
  (0, 71808)    0.024035496522681176
  (0, 71074)    0.10259091123985954
  (0, 71068)    0.029069548629712276
  (0, 69111)    0.034672135261239224
  (0, 67955)    0.028020431168325064
  (0, 67295)    0.08966352907219226
  (0, 67271)    0.07466916102470975
  (0, 65680)    0.07633327292778912
  (0, 65582)    0.06302560391647538
  : :
  (33176, 14634)    0.06590551471195294
  (33176, 13543)    0.10461979226562991
  (33176, 13456)    0.13212282016340926
  (33176, 13334)    0.06442044467320687
  (33176, 13305)    0.08944519590878486
  (33176, 12986)    0.12141184143278444
  (33176, 12422)    0.07503587946081758
  (33176, 12078)    0.055370951522851375
  (33176, 12072)    0.05526753229884225
  (33176, 11351)    0.06005084727061667
  (33176, 11228)    0.04758053186984806
  (33176, 10976)    0.05649949678481916
  (33176, 10386)    0.03386386645277619
  (33176, 10180)    0.0874550089809755
  (33176, 10178)    0.10022395321154942
  (33176, 8422) 0.041895956703497765
  (33176, 5090) 0.042348177892434245
  (33176, 4572) 0.03430959811550174
  (33176, 3952) 0.03911645709026695
  (33176, 3565) 0.053420564985650364
  (33176, 3191) 0.03409252329522664
  (33176, 2574) 0.06556944792700295
  (33176, 2168) 0.03405895402746877
  (33176, 804)  0.11463326965951669
  (33176, 483)  0.03643119719769616

print(m0.target)
>>>>
job_template_id
0a1503121721392501811267    22.04
0a1503121721483290712244    24.51
0a1503121721565752313317    24.51
0a1503121722295642819615    39.45
0a1503121722362699720498    52.41
                            ...  
z16092315345694244686913    33.38
z1609240007114166452790f    33.89
z1609261351036745094491a    28.85
z1609261614080106125891c    17.61
z16092623135294934160908     43.4
```

As you can see, m0 is an instance of a user defined class; it's essentially just a data wrapper. If you need more info therein, see my related question [Python NLP - ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'UKN'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60580392/python-nlp-valueerror-could-not-convert-string-to-float-ukn?noredirect=1#comment107176443_60580392)

Comment: I think 'UNK' is doing a problem. It is in string format may be at one of the data points. You should try to convert it in float format

Comment: @DhavalTaunk - what does this mean? It's an error raised by sklearn. So 'UNK' is not an input supplied (to my knowledge).

Comment: Are you sure for all the data points? Did you verified it for all the data points

Comment: Please, add the code for the tf-idf generating to the question. The problem may lie there.